# Error 102 when pulling html into an iframe on fb page

Tags: html, facebook, iframe, tabs

I am currently trying to move away from the FBML I was using and over into iframes.
Followed steps to make a simple welcome page/tab that should be here:

http://www.facebook.com/reallyghey2?v=app_310228345675351

I uploaded the first version and it didn't work. I got Error 102.

Error 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED): The server refused the connection.

After a few days off at Christmas, I checked the page and it was working fine (?)
So I edited it and made some alterations. Now the tab is showing Error 102 again.

Can someone please shed some light on why it is doing this? And how to correct the error.

Answer (score 3):

ok got this one sorted - I hadn't enabled SSL on my domain.

Now that I have it all works perfectly - in case anyone else was interested...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried from a different computer/network? Could be a local setting issue, are you using Chrome and if so have you tried using the app in incognito mode? more  @ http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=17356c1d1a1249eb&hl=en

Comment: hi and thanks so much for your answer. 

It's not a Chrome related thing - I get the same error on Firefox 

Unable to connect 
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at www.internetbling.com. 

Also I asked several fans on my page to try out the link and they all got the same result - on IE, Chrome, Safari and Firefox. 

What I don't understand is why it wasn't working, then it was, and now it isn't again. I have no htaccess set up on my domain...